# I want to know how i can refresh a modal and display it after update data with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

How can I put the ajax responsed html to inside of the modal without refresh the all page?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "Post",
  url: '@Url.Action("ModifierPM", "Mode")',
  data: data,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (response) {
     
     $("#modalModifPM").modal('hide');
     // i want to show reaponse data in this Modal
     // within not refresh all the page, just the MODAL will be updated and appeared
     $("#modalTMRs").modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's very board, but depending on your modal structure and without seeing that we can't tell you for sure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your response comes from a Parital View Result (that's mean, your response is html text), you can put all of the response into the modal body;

```
$.ajax({
  type: "Post",
  url: '@Url.Action("ModifierPM", "Mode")',
  data: data,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (response) {
       $("#modalModifPM").modal('hide');
       // this line finds the modal body in two step and puts the response data inside of it
       $("#modalTMRs").find(".modal-body").html(response);
       $("#modalTMRs").modal('show');
    }
});
```

As you seen in the comment line, there are more and better ways to find modal body. For example;

```
$("#modalTMRs .modal-body").html(response); // one space between parent and child
```

Another way is to write an id directly to modal body div and find it via id;
If your modal html like below;

```
<div id="modalTMRs" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="modalTMRs-modal-body">  THATS THE ID
    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then you can reach in one step;

```
$("#modalTMRs-modal-body").html(response);
```

Examples can be more.. :P

If yuor response just Json list then you can convert it a table client side;

```
 var exampleJsonResult = [
    { "id":1, "name":"test1", "statu":"OK" },
    { "id":2, "name":"test2", "statu":"OK" },
    { "id":3, "name":"test3", "statu":"OK" },
 ];
```

And result function can be like this;

```
 function makeTable(json) {
    let htmlTable = "<table>";
    json.forEach(item=>{
      htmlTable += "<tr>";
      htmlTable += "<td>" + item.id + "</td>";
      htmlTable += "<td>" + item.name + "</td>";
      htmlTable += "<td>" + item.statu + "</td>";
      htmlTable += "</tr>";
    });
    htmlTable += "</table>";
    return htmlTable;
 }
```

When you send result data to this function, this will give you a table. Next step, append the table where ever you want, like explained above.

In this sample, you have to know data model and call values by name.

If you want to make more elastic table maker, you must change the response model like this;

```
 var exampleJsonResult2 = [
    [ 1, "test1", "OK", 234.2 ],
    [ 2, "test2", "NO", 345.6 ],
    [ 3, "test3", "OK", 456.7 ],
    [ 4, "test4", "NO", 678.9 ],
 ];
```

This json is a list of list, made from each item is a object list. The advantage is this model; you can iterate via loops, no need to know property names.

```
 function makeTable2(json) {
    let htmlTable = "<table>";
    json.forEach(item=>{
      htmlTable += "<tr>";
      item.forEach(prop => htmlTable += "<td>" + prop + "</td>");
      htmlTable += "</tr>";
    });
    htmlTable += "</table>";
    return htmlTable;
 }
```

makeTable2(exampleJsonResult2) is the table string!

Comment: Thank you for your response, i find this method perfect but when i return to my modal i found it empty , the of my modal is  like this <div class="modal-body" id="modalTMRs-modal-body">
          <table class="test">
            <tr>
              <th>Nom Parametre</th>
              <th>Valeur par defaut</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>

          </table>

        </div>   /// i fill  the field with AJAX call

Comment: Ok, then your partial view must return only table waht you want. Remember Layout must be setted null inside of the partial view.

Comment: I fill the table like this for (var i in response) {
              
                      var ligne = '<tr id=' + response[i].idParam + '><td>' + response[i].nomParam + '</td><td>' + response[i].valParDet + '</a></td><td><a href="#" type="button" onclick="ModifierPM(' + "'" + response[i].idParam + "'" + ', ' + "'" + response[i].idMode + "'" + ', ' + "'" + response[i].nomParam + "'" + ', ' + "'" + response[i].valParDet + "'" + ', ' + "'" + response[i].idTMR + "'" + ')" </td></tr>';$("table.test").append(ligne);

Comment: and the method in Controller was public JsonResult GetParametresModeC(int idMode)
and return  return Json("sucess ", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // or  erreur depending on the case